# Question about SQL Server replication scalability

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

I'm hoping someone has some insight to offer here.  I'm in an environment where we have a central database server with a database of around 20GB and individual database servers across about 200 facilities.  The intention is to run a copy of our application at each facility pointing at their local server, but to sync all databases in both directions as often as possible (no more than 10,000 rows affected per day, individual rows on average 1.5kb).  Due to varying connectivity, a facility could be offline for a week or two at times and it needs to catch up once back online.

Question: Using pull replication with the merge strategy, are there practical limits that would affect our environment?  At 50, 100, 200 facilities, what negative effects can we expect to see, if any?  What kind of bandwidth expectations should we have for the central server (I'm finding very little about this number anywhere I look)?

I appreciate any thoughts or guidance you may have.

Comment: Are you expecting replication to be one-way or two-way?  What interval are you thinking (latency)?  1.5 kb is the total data per day, or per row?

Comment: Per row, just taking storage space per table divided by row count, on average.  We need two-way replication but latency can be fairly high.  We might tweak it between different facilities, but every 2-4 hours would probably work fine.  We're still trying to determine what's really ideal for our environment, but it's definitely not realtime.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the math looks like this:

1.5 kb (per row) * 10000 rows = 15 GB per day (min) incoming, at every one of your 50 to 200 sites.

15 GB * (50 to 200 sites) = .7 to 3 TB per day (min), sent from your central server.

Your sites will be fairly busy (15 GB per day) and your hub will be very busy (3 TB per day)

So bandwidth might be a concern.  You will definitely want to monitor your bandwidth and throughput.  Negative side effects would be periodic slowness at your hub (every synch).

Comment: Great info!  There will definitely be variability for number of rows per site so hopefully the number ends up smaller.  As for the per row size, does replication somehow just send diff info when it's an update or would it be the full data of the entire row?  Also, is there any guidance on memory/cpu requirements for the hub based on number of sites?  I'm assuming the hub database itself is larger to accommodate sync metadata, or is that completely handled by the sites being in pull mode?

Comment: There are options for how replication sends data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910008/how-can-i-minimize-the-data-in-a-sql-replication The size of the hub should be based on the size of the data and its use. Replication is only one "use". Considering the number of hubs, I would expect something pretty big, but not 200x your spokes. More like 10-20x. Just keep in mind that for each spoke who is pulling, the hub still needs to respond to the pull and keep things straight. For each synch, both are doing nearly equal work (the hub and the client) (per synch = per client).

Comment: Awesome!  Final question... if a site is down for too long, is there a way to "proxy" the hub by physically visiting a site with a copy of the database to do a manual two-way sync?  My fear is the only way would be to take a backup from the facility, mount it somewhere online and run the sync, then drive it back to the facility.  Is there any other way to use a "middleman" to initialize at the hub, update at the facility, then final update/merge back at the hub (meaning only one trip to the facility)?

Comment: If you run your DB servers as VMs, those can be somewhat portable. That would be one way. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure you could choose to break replication and connect to another server as much as you want. The initial connection might be fairly busy for a while as it evaluates (depending on row-count and delta).  I recommend trying a few experiments (non-prod) to get an idea of how much work & time this would cost you.